# Получение заголовков всех запущенных программ

Tags: c#

Как в C# получить заголовки всех открытых программ? Ну или только нужной программы.
Под заголовками я имею ввиду, к примеру, вот это:

[image: img]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  using System.Diagnostics;
  ...

  Process[] procs = Process.GetProcesses();

  foreach (Process p in procs)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(p.MainWindowTitle);
  }
```

Comment: похоже на правду но у меня открытых окон намного больше чем вывел скрипт. есть ситуации, когда в одной программе много окон открыто и нужно что б в список попали все эти окна

Comment: чтобы быть точным мне нужно получить весь список как в столбце "задачи" диспетчера задач http://gyazo.com/aba579c8a170335b28e84257eb3c0d93

Comment: У меня возвращает все, что запущено. Однако некоторые процессы не имеют WindowTitle и возвращается пустая строка.
Вам может p.ProcessName нужен?

Comment: я может не понимаю чего, но это ведь одно и то же.
скрин, что я прислал в последнем комментарии это список всех открытых программ. у всех открытых программ есть "название". вот список этих названий мне и нужен.
в том коде, что Вы предложили выводит список не всех окон. часть почему то пустая. хотя у меня нет ни одной открытой пограммы с пустым "названием"
в общем нужен такой список который тут: http://gyazo.com/aba579c8a170335b28e84257eb3c0d93

только не список названий процессов, а список названий всех открытых программ и их окон.

Comment: нет,  p.ProcessName это список процессов. а мне нужны "названия" окон

Comment: Ну, `MainWindowTitle` означает, что вы получаете лишь «главное» с точки зрения системы окно.

Answer (score 3):

Проще всего решить задачу используя функцию `EnumDesktopWindows`. Готовый пример можно найти на [pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.EnumDesktopWindows).

Результат:

[image: Результат]

Если нужно отфильтровать из списка окон гаджеты и кнопку Пуск, то достаточно проверить у окна наличие стиля `WS_CAPTION`:

```
const int GWL_STYLE = -16;
const int WS_CAPTION = 0xC00000;

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);

private bool HasCaption(IntPtr hWnd)
{
    return (GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE) & WS_CAPTION) == WS_CAPTION;
}

//...
if (user32.IsWindowVisible(hWnd) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(strTitle) == false && HasCaption(hWnd)) {
//...
```

Comment: Всем спасибо за участие! Почему то не могу голосовать за Ваши ответы.
Хватило решения Veikedo, т.к. почему то из всех окон программы в этом списке оказывалось только последнее испьзованное. А мне это и нужно было!